# How to enable session replication for WSO2 API Manager 1.8?

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-api-manager, session-replication

I'm using 2 instances of WSO2 API Manager 1.8. Each instance is deployed on an Ubuntu instance and fronted with a HAProxy load balancer.

```
HAProxy -> 192.168.11.1
API Manager 1 -> 192.168.11.2
API Manager 2 -> 192.168.11.3
```

What I want to do is enable session replication for API Manager 1 and 2 instances, so that once an user is logged into API Manager 1 particular user will be automatically logged into API Manager 2 as well(session will be replicated in both instances). Otherwise there will be problems when user is logged into one API Manager instance and HAProxy redirect the user to other API Manager instace.

*There is a [guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AS520/Clustering+and+Http+Session+Replication) for WSO2 Application Server but not for the API Manager.*

How can I get it done?

Comment: By API Manager, you mean API Store/API Publisher, right?

Comment: Yes, I have separate API Store/API Publisher for each instance. What I want to do is sync API Store sessions so that users won't feel a difference whether it's API Manager 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API manager doesn't support session replication itself .What you have to do is configure load balancer for session affinity (sticky session).Use JSESSIONID for sticky session.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, Could you please point me a guide which helps to get it done?

Comment: http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/03/29/load-balancing-affinity-persistence-sticky-sessions-what-you-need-to-know/